# Spark Streaming with Hbase

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, bigdata

i am trying to get data from hbase ,For all the tuto I find that to have the data of Hbase I am obliged to go through Kafka, is it possible an integration between spark streaming and hbase directly without including Kafka in the chain
Thanks .

Comment: yes its possible as we have done the same without using kafka. see below example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it possible an integration between spark streaming and hbase
>   directly without including Kafka

Yes.. its possible as we have done the same without using kafka. 
see the below example [JavaHBaseStreamingBulkPutExample](https://github.com/Will-Grindelwald/Spark-Kafka/blob/master/project/ibd/src/main/java/com/ljc/hbase/hbase/spark/example/JavaHBaseStreamingBulkPutExample.java)

```
package org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.example.hbasecontext;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.JavaHBaseContext;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaReceiverInputDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;

/**
 * This is a simple example of BulkPut with Spark Streaming
 */
final public class JavaHBaseStreamingBulkPutExample {

  private JavaHBaseStreamingBulkPutExample() {}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length < 4) {
      System.out.println("JavaHBaseBulkPutExample  " +
              "{host} {port} {tableName}");
      return;
    }

    String host = args[0];
    String port = args[1];
    String tableName = args[2];

    SparkConf sparkConf =
            new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaHBaseStreamingBulkPutExample " +
                    tableName + ":" + port + ":" + tableName);

    JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

    try {
      JavaStreamingContext jssc =
              new JavaStreamingContext(jsc, new Duration(1000));

      JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> javaDstream =
              jssc.socketTextStream(host, Integer.parseInt(port));

      Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();

      JavaHBaseContext hbaseContext = new JavaHBaseContext(jsc, conf);

      hbaseContext.streamBulkPut(javaDstream,
              TableName.valueOf(tableName),
              new PutFunction());
    } finally {
      jsc.stop();
    }
  }

  public static class PutFunction implements Function<String, Put> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Put call(String v) throws Exception {
      String[] part = v.split(",");
      Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(part[0]));

      put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes(part[1]),
              Bytes.toBytes(part[2]),
              Bytes.toBytes(part[3]));
      return put;
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: I have problem to import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.JavaHBaseContext. i add maven dependence as this 
            groupId - org.apache.hbase
            artifactId - hbase-spark
            version - 2.0.0-alpha4

Comment: you  GitHub project also deleted

Comment: pls refer latest raise new qusetion this is 2 years old